# Run EXE from Windows From pass in static inputs

Tags: c#, console-application

currently I have a process that runs, but it requires the user to enter

```
y <return>
<return>
```

The code I am using is as follows

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
string exepath = Directory.GetParent(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ToString();
Process proc = new Process();
psi.FileName = exepath + @"\lib\dnaml";
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.Arguments = "y\r \r";
psi.UserShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo = psi;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

I want to hard type these inputs in.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't illustrate the input being utilised.

Comment: Did you check if `Process` or related classes have any methods to interact with the process? \

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Arguments` property corresponds to the command-line, not data entered via standard input.

The `RedirectStandardInput` property is part of the puzzle.  Then you also need to write to the stream connected to the `StandardInput` property.  Also note that standard input redirection is incompatible with `ShellExecute`, it needs `CreateProcess` to work.  So set `UseShellExecute = false`.

```
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo = psi;
proc.Start();
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("y ");
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: This was the answer I was just submitting.  This should work.